# Query is not working?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('pr.req_id,pr.requested_user_id,pr.requested_date,pr.requested_amount,ft.user_name');
$this->db->from('individual AS ft');
$this->db->join('payout_release_requests AS pr', 'ft.id = pr.requested_user_id', 'INNER');
$this->db->join('product as p', 'p.product_id = ft.product_id');
$this->db->where('ft.active', "yes");
$this->db->where('pr.requested_amount >=', 'p.minimum_payment');
$this->db->where('pr.status', "pending");
$this->db->order_by('pr.requested_date', "DESC");
$query = $this->db->get();
```

given code is produce output but

```
$this->db->where('pr.requested_amount >=', 'p.minimum_payment');
```

is not checking?

Comment: Post the errors too. As I've checked it its not throwing an error for me

Comment: result set is generating problem is given condition is not checking

Comment: Add  p.minimum_payment in the select list to check if this really does not check.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$this->db->where('pr.requested_amount >= p.minimum_payment');
```